# Not validating CI form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out why when I run this controller and it tries to run the form it won't validate it. Any ideas? Everytime I try to submit the form it comes back with my failed validation error that There was a problem submitting the form! Please refresh the window and try again!

http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/forgotpassword

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Forgotpassword extends CI_Controller { 

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('kow_auth');  
    $this->load->model('kow_auth/users');           
}   

public function index()
{
    //Config Defaults Start
    $msgBoxMsgs = array();//msgType = dl, info, warn, note, msg
    $cssPageAddons = '';//If you have extra CSS for this view append it here
    $jsPageAddons = '<script src="http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/assets/js/forgotvalidate.js"></script>';//If you have extra JS for this view append it here
    $metaAddons = '';//Sometimes there is a need for additional Meta Data such in the case of Facebook addon's
    $siteTitle = '';//alter only if you need something other than the default for this view.
    //Config Defaults Start


    //examples of how to use the message box system (css not included).
    //$msgBoxMsgs[] = array('msgType' => 'dl', 'theMsg' => 'This is a Blank Message Box...');

    /**********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, Start*/

    if (!$this->session->userdata('xtr') == "yes") {
        $bodyContent = "forgot_password_form";//which view file
    } else {
        $bodyContent = "dashboard";//which view file
    }

    $bodyType = "full";//type of template

    /***********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, End*/

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, Start.
    //If msgBoxMsgs array has anything in it, if so displays it in view, else does nothing.      
    if(count($msgBoxMsgs) !== 0)
    {
        $msgBoxes = $this->msgboxes->buildMsgBoxesOutput(array('display' => 'show', 'msgs' =>$msgBoxMsgs));
    }
    else
    {
        $msgBoxes = array('display' => 'none');
    }

    if($siteTitle == '')
    {
        $siteTitle = $this->metatags->SiteTitle(); //reads 
    }

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, End.

    $this->data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes;
    $this->data['cssPageAddons'] = $cssPageAddons;//if there is any additional CSS to add from above Variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['jsPageAddons'] = $jsPageAddons;//if there is any addictional JS to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['metaAddons'] = $metaAddons;//if there is any addictional meta data to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['pageMetaTags'] = $this->metatags->MetaTags();//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['siteTitle'] = $siteTitle;//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['bodyType'] = $bodyType;
    $this->data['bodyContent'] = $bodyContent;
    $this->load->view('usermanagement/index', $this->data);
}

function forgot_password_submit()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) 
    {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'There was a problem submitting the form! Please refresh the window and try again!'));    
    }
    else
    {
        if (!is_null($user_data = $this->kow_auth->forgot_password($this->input->post('username')))) 
        {
            // Send email with password activation link
            $this->kow_auth->send_email('forgot_password', 'KOW Manager Forgot Password Email', $user_data);
        }   
    }          
}

}

/* End of file forgotpassword.php */ 
/* Location: ./application/controllers/forgotpassword.php */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're including a jQuery Validation script that doesn't apply to this form. Line 66 of the page you linked to is this:

```
<script src="http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/assets/js/forgotvalidate.js"></script>
```

which POST's the form data to the following URL:

```
http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/register/register_submit
```

That page, in turn, is giving you the error message:

```
{"error":"yes","message":"There was a problem submitting the form! Please refresh the window and try again!"}
```

I'm assuming you want the "Forgot Password" page to POST to itself (http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/forgotpassword) instead.

You'll either need to get rid of the jQuery Validation script, or modify it so it works with the "Forgot Password" page.

Comment: @JeffDavidson: You're welcome, Jeff. Good luck with your project!